# spring cloud gateway oauth2 insert dynamic oauth2 configs

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, cloud, gateway

how can I inject a configuration dynamic in the spring boot security  context ?

the object look like:

```
    ClientRegistration clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
                    .withRegistrationId(realmName)
                    .clientId(keycloak.getClientGlbId())
                    .clientSecret(keycloak.getClientGlbSecret())
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                    .redirectUri(keycloak.getClientGlbRedirectUri())
                    .issuerUri(keycloak.getClientGlbIssuerUri().concat(realmName))
                    .authorizationUri(keycloak.getHost().concat("realms").concat(realmName).concat("/protocol/openid-connect/auth"))
                    .userInfoUri(keycloak.getHost().concat("realms").concat(realmName).concat("/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"))
                    .tokenUri(keycloak.getHost().concat("realms").concat(realmName).concat("/protocol/openid-connect/token"))
                    .build();
```

on runtime this is working

```
@Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {

        
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(this.googleClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration googleClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("google")
                .clientId("google-client-id")
                .clientSecret("google-client-secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
                .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone")
                .authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")
                .tokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
                .userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
                .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
                .jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")
                .clientName("Google")
                .build();
    }
```

also discovered after analyzing on the source code of org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client ClientsConfiguredCondition that the env spring.security.oauth2.client.registration is keeping all the oauth2 configs.

```
private static final Bindable<Map<String, OAuth2ClientProperties.Registration>> STRING_REGISTRATION_MAP = Bindable
            .mapOf(String.class, OAuth2ClientProperties.Registration.class);

    @Override
    public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        ConditionMessage.Builder message = ConditionMessage.forCondition("OAuth2 Clients Configured Condition");
        Map<String, OAuth2ClientProperties.Registration> registrations = getRegistrations(context.getEnvironment());
        if (!registrations.isEmpty()) {
            return ConditionOutcome.match(message.foundExactly("registered clients " + registrations.values().stream()
                    .map(OAuth2ClientProperties.Registration::getClientId).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))));
        }
        return ConditionOutcome.noMatch(message.notAvailable("registered clients"));
    }

    private Map<String, OAuth2ClientProperties.Registration> getRegistrations(Environment environment) {
        return Binder.get(environment).bind("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration", STRING_REGISTRATION_MAP)
                .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
    }
```

The question is: how to inject/add oauth2 providers/configurations dynamically ?